# Joomla login redirecting to 404 page?

Tags: joomla, http-status-code-404, joomla2.5, moodle, joomdle

I am currently working with Joomla 2.5, joomdle and moodle. 
My Joomla site is redirecting me to 404 page when I login but only on the home page every other page will allow me to log in, the url from the homepage login is http://www.mywebsite.com//index.php?Itemid=223

When you take away one of the forward slashes before the index the link works.
(http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?Itemid=223)

How do I fix this problem??

Comment: Create a HTML redirection replacing // with / on 404. Modify that inside joomla (theres a 404.html or sth like that on your server).

Comment: Do I need a Plugin for redirecting? Sorry I am new to joomla

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Custom_404_Error_Page <-- Create a custom 404 page, then redirect to the article the user should normally go (instead of a 404 article)